# Issue with moving website root folder with Twig

Tags: php, twig

We have an issue with our current site - our original developer used Twig as the basis for our site, and that developer is no longer available to us.  We have need to make modifications, but I'm running into an issue.

I am not a web developer.  I can get by with simple changes, and for now, that's sufficient.  In order to test some of the changes I'm planning on implementing, I've made a complete copy of the root folder and all subfolders on our site, and place the copy into a new subfolder from the root.  I had expected that if I pointed to the index.php in this newly created folder, that my site would run from there, but it flat-out refuses to function.  It continues to attempt to load from the original root folder, as if somehow the root folder name is embedded.

I verified that none of the Twig setup implies specific folder names, here's our twig statements in our index.php file:

```
require_once 'Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
global $twig;
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => 'cache/','debug' => true,));
```

Seems to me I'm missing something quite simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out!  I keep thinking that the root folder name is locked in somewhere, but I've looked through the entire contents of our site, and cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Define `flat-out does not run`? Please post the `.htacess`

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Doesn't run correctly, links show up as using the root folder, not the current folder, for example.  The site can be found at http://www.mkcontrols.com/MKCFF/index.php, if you move over the links at the top, all will show www.mkcontrols.com as the root, not www.mkcontrols.com/MKCFF.

Comment: So is this running symfony/silix/slim/.. ?

Comment: What in the world would that have to do with anything?  It's a TWIG issue, all I'm trying to find out is why TWIG is not recognizing the new folder as it's root folder.   Oh well, I think I'm looking for help in the wrong place...

Comment: To be honest, It's not a twig issue but a misconfiguration of the used framework. Good luck figuring it out then

Comment: Probably would make sense to backup the entire served directory, which appears to be `MKCFF`. I would copy that (all contents) to a new folder name, and then modify your apache config to serve that. You haven't indicated what problem you want to fix in Twig. @DarkBee 's questions about the framework are valid.